# Repository for myfaces 2

Tags: maven, jsf-2, myfaces

Please I need to use myfaces 2 in a maven project.
where can I found the repository.

i have found just the dependency
`<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.myfaces.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>myfaces-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0-alpha</version>
</dependency>`

Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go:

```
https://repository.apache.org/content/repositories/releases/org/apache/myfaces/core/
```